# Given a directory, how do I find out where a class is

Tags: java, jar

Consider that I have a directory full of jars.  Is there a java command that I can type into the command prompt that will tell me which jars a class can be loaded from?

Comment: While the selected answer works, I was actually trying to figure out where a class got loaded from.  It probably seems basic to Java pros, but for those who don't know here's a tip I just discovered.  Run java with the -verbose flag and it will output to the standard out every time a class is loaded and from where!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Java commands” (whatever they may be) are usually not entered on the command line. You might try a simple grep, though:

```
 # grep 'my.super.cool.Stuff' *.jar
```

Theoretically the dots need to be escaped to prevent them from matching any character but this will generally give you an idea where a class is located.

Answer (score 1):

There's an app for this, [FindClass](http://www.nsydenham.net/java/FindClass/FindClass.shtml) that can provide clean output.  They have source as well, they may just be grepping through the jars.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at "Swiss File Knife" on Sourceforge (http://sourceforge.net/projects/swissfileknife/). To search for some class named, say, QueryParameter, use

```
>sfk larc -dir "*.jar" +filter -+QueryParameter
gwt\gwt-dev.jar\\org\apache\xalan\lib\sql\QueryParameter.class
```

The JAR file is mentioned before the double backslash, the path within the JAR is after that.

Once you get used to the compact syntax of SFK, you'll use it for many, many things. Excellent companion to grep, find, and the like.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know when and where classes are loaded into the JVM **at runtime**, you can use the `-verbose:class` option on the "java" command.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this:

**findclass.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ 2 != $# ] ; then
     echo  "Usage: $0 directory class"
     exit 1
fi

for i in $1/*.jar; do
    if unzip -l $i | grep -q "$2.class"; then 
        echo "Found $2 in $i"
   fi
done
```